# How to convert an array of json objects to string and then convert it back to array of json objects in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I have an array of json objects like this:

```
var b = [{"n":11,"np":11,"g":2,"v":10},{"n":6,"np":6,"g":4,"v":5},{"n":8,"np":8,"g":4,"v":10},{"n":9,"np":9,"g":4,"v":10}]
```

Then I convert each object of the array to a string:

```
b = b.map(function(card){
            return JSON.stringify(card);
            
        });
```

Then I convert the array to string as well using the join function:

```
b = b.join("|");
```

This is the output of b:

```
{"n":11,"np":11,"g":2,"v":10}|{"n":6,"np":6,"g":4,"v":5}|{"n":8,"np":8,"g":4,"v":10}|{"n":9,"np":9,"g":4,"v":10}
```

Now I need to convert everything back so I use split:

```
b = b.split("|");
```

Output:

```
[ '{"n":11,"np":11,"g":2,"v":10}',
'{"n":6,"np":6,"g":4,"v":5}',
'{"n":8,"np":8,"g":4,"v":10}',
'{"n":9,"np":9,"g":4,"v":10} ]
```

Now I try to go through each element and convert back to json object with JSON.parse:

```
var newArr = b.forEach(function(card){
                    
                    var newCard = JSON.parse(card);
                    return newCard;
                    
                });
```

However, after that it gives me "undefined" as an output and if I try to use pop() to remove one element from the new array it gives me an error:

```
var singleCard = newArr.pop();
```

Error:
----- process errTypeError: Cannot read property 'pop' of undefined

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just stringifying the array to begin with? `const string = JSON.stringify(b); const newArr = JSON.parse(string);`

Comment: I actually save the string in a redis server, then I have to convert it back when retrieving from the server

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the last step when getting `newArr`, [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't return an array, use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead:

```js
var b = [{"n":11,"np":11,"g":2,"v":10},{"n":6,"np":6,"g":4,"v":5},{"n":8,"np":8,"g":4,"v":10},{"n":9,"np":9,"g":4,"v":10}]

b = b.map(function(card){ return JSON.stringify(card); });

b = b.join("|");

b = b.split("|");

var newArr = b.map(function(card){ 
  var newCard = JSON.parse(card);
  return newCard;
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answear, but it didn't solve the problem. I have found out the problem just now and posted the solution!

Comment: It's the same as your solution, in every iteration in .map, the parsed json of the stringified card is returned

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem:
It turned out that my last output was not a simple array, but a JSON array

```
[ '{"n":11,"np":11,"g":2,"v":10}',
'{"n":6,"np":6,"g":4,"v":5}',
'{"n":8,"np":8,"g":4,"v":10}',
'{"n":9,"np":9,"g":4,"v":10} ]
```

So all I had to do was this after using the split:

```
b = b.map(JSON.parse)
```